# Loop through controls asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, loops

I'm trying to make a function to disable all controls in a specific page.

When I loop through, all controls are disabled except the ones inside the div that is set to runat="server"

This is a general view of the design:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
   <div id="wrapper">
   <%-- 1st set of ASP controls --%>
      <div id="Main" runat="server">
         <%-- 2nd set ASP of controls --%>
      </div>
   </div>
<form>
```

My code looks like this:

```
For Each c As Control In Page.Controls
   For Each ctrl As Control In c.Controls
      'disabling controls 
   Next
Next
```

I want to use this function in all my pages, please could you let me know how to loop through the divs that are runat="Server"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is disable/enable controls that are children of the page, and also controls that are children of controls that are children of the page.
For this you will need to use a recursive function.
Something like:

```
private void DisableChildControls(ControlCollection controls, int depthLimit)
{
   if(depthLimit <= 0)
      return;
   foreach(var ctl in controls)
   {
      ctl.Enabled = false;
      if(ctl.Controls.Count > 0)
      {
         DisableChildControls(ctl.Controls, --depthLimit);
      }
    }
}
```

In the page load event you call start the traversal using:

```
if(this.Controls.Count > 0)
   DisableChildControls(this.Controls, 2); //If you want the depth to be two levels.
```

This will recursivly disable controls down the tree, up to the limit you specified.
Just consider that for a complex page, this recursive operation can take a considerable amount of time.

Also note that for better or worse, this will only loop through controls marked with `runat="server"`

Comment: Thank you a lot man I based my solution on your code it really helped !

Comment: @SalemRady - Great! Happy my example helped you out.

Comment: @SalemRady - Added a depth limit parameter for completeness. I thought you might also be interested in the implementation.